# Get DateTime Format for the List filed

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have a Sharepoint list item with a date field. 
 When I read the value for the item it gives me in format of MM/DD/YYYY. But my local machine is having different DateTime format as DD/MM/YYYY. So while parsing to DateTime either it changes the value or thows exception as Invalid DateTime.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(item["DateTime"]);
```

How can I get the DateTime format for the field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. We can get DateTime Format using Regional Settings property.

```
ClientContext.Load(f_Web, website => website.RegionalSettings)
ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var format = f_Web.RegionalSettings.DateFormat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please tried to handle null exception for Date. Other wise it work.

```
if(item["DateTime"]!=null && item["DateTime"]!="")
{
      DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(item["DateTime"]);
      Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
}
```

Comment: That is not the concern. I need DateTime format

Comment: As you said it's through exception that why I said you handle null exection